# How to animate modelvalidation in MVC with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, controller

I´m new here. please be patient with me :)

An open question, if I´m using asp.net MVC model validation. Can I get my `@html.ValidationMessageFor` to use javascript effects on display when my controller action returns the error message?

CSS i an option, but my question targets javascript on model validation specifically.

I´m aware of unobtrusive javascript and validate.js.

sample code from my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
{
<fieldset>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new {@type="email", @class ="form-control", @placeholder="E-post", @required="required"})
        <i class="form-control-feedback fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

And my model validationattribute looks like this:

```
public class general_customerMetaData
{
    [CreateAccountValidation("isEmailAvailable", "Account", ErrorMessage = "E-postadressen används redan!")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "Lösenorden matchar inte")]
    public string passwordValidation { get; set; }
}
```

My error message gets displayed, but I don't know how to use javascript effects when passing result from the controller to view.

I appreciate all your help and tips.

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: Generally you do not need any JavaScript for animation. Subtle effects are best achieved with CSS `transition` while more complicated animations are done with CSS3 `@keyframe`-animations. You may need JavaScript to trigger the animations (such as adding or removing class-names for `transition`) but that's generally it - unless you really need to target Internet Explorer 7 for some reason.

Comment: Error messages have the `class="field-validation-error"` so you could always hide then when the page is first loaded, and then animate the (e.g. `$('.field-validation-error').hide().fadeIn('slow');`)

Comment: @Dai thank you for your reply.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okey will try, i will come back when tested :)